# React.js Запрос на получение данных из json возвращает index.html

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack, fetch, create-react-app

```
fetch('../../../../public/clients.json')
      .then(res => console.log(res.text()))
```

В итоге в консоль выводится:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵  <head>↵    <meta charset="utf-8">↵ <title>Test</title>↵  </head>↵  <body>↵    <div id="root"></div>↵  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></body>↵</html>↵"
```

Вообще мне нужно отправлять запрос через XmlHttpRequest, поэтому прошу не предлагать импортировать файл, а потом читать его через .map

Comment: У вас явно проблема с настройкой сервака.

Comment: @Suvitruf У меня только клиент, нет сервера

Comment: Вы точно понимаете, как работают клиент-серверные приложения? Я, так понимаю, вы это пока только тестируете локально в IDEA? У вас там локальные dev сервер поднимается. Когда вы это зальёте на VPS, то вам нужно будет настроить какой-нибудь веб-сервер.

Comment: @Suvitruf да, понимаю. Но в этом случае мне необходимо именно так

Comment: Сервер не отдает вам json. Возможно из-за ошибки сервера, возможно из-за настроек. Это весь html? Или в нем много текста об ошибке?